# how to write javascript function as string in php?

Tags: php, javascript, html, string

I have one line in php file like this:

```
<a class="hide-if-no-js" onclick="findPosts.open( 'media[]','<?php echo $post->ID ?>' ); return false;" href="#the-list">Attach</a>
```

I need to write this line as a string in a php function, I tried this:

```
$output .="<a class='hide-if-no-js' onclick='findPosts.open( 'media[]','$id' ); return false;' href='#the-list'>'$linktext'</a>";
```

Seems the quote around 'media[]' is wrong and made the html of this line messed up. Could anybody help correct me?

Comment: If you need to output this, why don't you output it directly *outside* the PHP script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$output .= "<a class=\"hide-if-no-js\" onclick=\"findPosts.open( 'media[]','$id' ); return false;\" href=\"#the-list\">$linktext</a>";
```

Your javascript string use single quote, so the html attribute should use double quote.

Comment: You could also use a `HEREDOC` or an output buffer to avoided having to use escaped quotes, although in this case either the attribute quotes or the embedded Javascript quotes would need to be reversed.

Comment: Also, are you saying HTML attributes are required by spec to use `"`?

Comment: As per the RFC, either double quotes or single quotes **can** be used for HTML attributes.

Comment: In *XHTML*. There's no indication that's the case here, and if you make a comment like that, it needs to be specific. That's how people get the idea it's required but can't remember why. And hey, y'know, I *prefer* double-quotes, but it's not factually correct by omission.

Comment: Thanks, xdazz! This line works! @Jared Farrish, I newly learn javascript, don't know what is reversed function. I will remember your suggestion in case I need it in the future. No, the html does not require space. xdazz's code works perfectly.

Comment: @Jenny - I meant you have two considerations for escaping quotes using double-quoted strings in your PHP; the others you only have one, but that case still exists in your html because you can't have the same quotes for attributes and within attribute values. So you would still have to reverse one set. Nothing to do with any JS function.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yep, I'm wrong, single quote is also allowed in xhtml, I just prefer double quotes for attribute.

Comment: @xdazz - Yeah, well, guess who also made the same mistake and learned in a very similar that it wasn't right...? `;)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$output .= '<a class="hide-if-no-js" onclick="findPosts.open( \'media[]\',\'' . $id . '\' ); return false;" href="#the-list">' . $linktext . '</a>';
```

**OR**

```
$output .= "<a class='hide-if-no-js' onclick='findPosts.open( \"media[]\", \"$id\" ); return false;' href='#the-list'>$linktext</a>";
```

Comment: Note there is a PHP variable in there that needs expansion using `"`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, Note that the variables are concatened with the string, so it will be returned normally

Comment: The original, *non-recorded* response didn't have the concatenation. And then you edited it initially and fixed it. I'm not blind.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, Maybe i forgot, anyway, thanks for your comment!